# Python Buffers, How Do They Work?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cpython

I'm currently surveying the Python buffer interface to see if it would help with optimizing my project. My project deals with large binary data files that both take an infeasible amount of memory to keep in memory (they can be multiple gigs when unpacked into Python data structures) and take too much time to unpack on demand (20-30 sec to fully or iteratively unpack). In contrast, the files are small enough (dozens or hundreds of megs) to store completely in memory in binary form (or page in via memory-mapping if necessary), and structured so they require minimal unpacking to use in place from e.g. C.

I've been reading some about buffers e.g. in the PEP, but there were a couple things that were not clear to me regarding using them to store structures in native form:

1. I know buffers have associated Struct-style format definitions, but
   where exactly do they get converted to Python versions on access?
   Does Python do this automatically based on the format definition, or
   does the buffer exporter do this via getitem or some such?
2. How much performance can you get out of using a buffer exporter to store large arrays of C structures? Would e.g. iterating over the
   entire file take the same amount of time as unpacking the entire
   file with Struct.unpack, or is it more efficient by various
   optimizations (e.g. if it were to only unpack a single structure
   element if you didn't access others within that structure)?
3. Is it possible to do auto-conversion of odd data types during element access? Specifically, some of these file formats are fond of
   using odd-length integers (e.g. 5 bytes long) to avoid using a
   fixed-size larger integer type. Could this by transparently and
   efficiently converted, or would I have to convert this to a fixed
   size in the exporter when allocating the actual buffer to conform to
   the Struct definition?